# I want hide a div according the page url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a div, its coming from other server. I am using a pyment gateway API all data coming from payment gateway website. but I want hide this on my site.
here is url https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Get URL
  var url = window.location.href;
  // Get DIV
  var msg = document.getElementById('mobileno');
  // Check if URL contains the keyword
  if( url.search( 'command=initiateTransaction' ) > 0 ) {
      // Display the message
      msg.style.display = "none";
      alert('hello this is not disable');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the div that you want to hide?

Comment: this is coming from other server .like payment gateway page

Comment: The server is sending HTML code? btw the link is useless

Comment: Where, in *your* html, is the div?  Just add a `<div style='display:none;'`>{server div}</div>` wrapper to hide it.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Your javascript cannot interact with pages from outside your domain.

Comment: Salketer@ it s any way  to hide this

Comment: no, a page on another domain is not under your control. What you're proposing seems to have some of the characteristics of a script injection attack.

Comment: How is the data coming from the other website? If it is via an iframe you can't change it.

Comment: I should add, if the situation is different and you're actually loading this HTML in from the gateway directly into your page's DOM (the same page where your script is located) via ajax, then you could potentially manipulate it to hide whatever you want, before you display it.

Comment: Björn Tantau @@ no its not coming from i frame its coming in div and form

Comment: if you show us how you are loading the data into your page, and a sample of what the HTML looks like then perhaps we can help.